# Why memcpy NOT work on this set<int> array case?

Tags: memcpy

a is set< int> ARRAY, I want to copy it to b. BUT...

```
int main(){

set<int> a[10];
a[1].insert(99);
a[3].insert(99);
if(a[1]==a[3])cout<<"echo"<<endl;

set<int> b[10];
memcpy(b,a,sizeof(a));
if(b[1]==b[3])cout<<"echo"<<endl;// latch up here, what happen?

return 0;}
```

Do you know What is computer doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the 'set' class you are using is a std::set? What makes you think that simplying memcpying the raw bytes of a std::set (or array of them, in this case) will work properly? This is highly dependent on the internal structure and implementation of the set class, and trying to do such a thing with anything more complicated than a primitive or array of primitives is almost guaranteed to give unexpected results. Doing this sort of raw byte manipulation when classes are involved is rarely going to be correct.

To do this properly you should iterate over the sets and use their '=' operator to assign them, which knows how to copy the contents properly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  b[i] = a[i];
}
```

Even better you can use std::copy:

```
std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));
```